# Granting full control permission on all sub-folders inside S3 bucket (excluding parent )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket called `my-bucket`... I have several sub-folders inside this bucket, let's call them: `sub-folder1`, `sub-folder2`, etc

I want `my-bucket-user` to have read permission to the bucket and full control permission to all of the sub-folders (so this user cannot write at the root level).

I have tried the following bucket policy, which specifically grants permission on each of the sub folders... but this policy would become too long if I have a lot of sub-folders.

```
{
  "Id": "MyBucketPolicy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
      "Sid": "ListPermissionOnMyBucket",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::773643377756:user/my-bucket-user"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "FullControlAccessOnSubFolder1",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/sub-folder1/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::773643377756:user/my-bucket-user"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "FullControlAccessOnSubFolder2",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/sub-folder2/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::773643377756:user/my-bucket-user"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a better way of writing this policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This policy permits listing the entire contents of the bucket, but only uploading/downloading to a sub-folder (not the root of the bucket):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, the expression `my-bucket/*/*` forces the requirement of a `/` in the Key of the object, meaning it is in a sub-folder.